# Swift 2 Handling of Multi-Level Objective C Error Passing

Tags: objective-c, swift, error-handling, swift2, encrypted-core-data-sql

I'm using `Encrypted Core Data` and want to follow an error on initialization. The `Objective C` header declares:

```
+(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)makeStoreWithStructOptions:(EncryptedStoreOptions *) options managedObjectModel:(NSManagedObjectModel *)objModel error:(NSError * __autoreleasing*)error;
```

However, the Swift bridging header interprets that as:

```
public class func makeStoreWithStructOptions(options: UnsafeMutablePointer<EncryptedStoreOptions>, managedObjectModel objModel: NSManagedObjectModel!, error: ()) throws -> NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
```

Note that it is requesting an object of type `()` instead of an `NSError`.

I have attempted to do:

```
var error: NSError? = nil
EncryptedStore.makeStoreWithOptions(options, managedObjectModel: myModel, error: &error)
```

But that results in an error saying the type is incorrect (and can't use the `&`)

If I instead try (hah!) this syntax, using an empty closure as a placeholder for its odd request:

```
do {
      try EncryptedStore.makeStoreWithOptions(options, managedObjectModel: myModel, error: {}())
    }catch{
      print(error)
    }
```

It compiles, but when an error is generated, it is not caught, though ECD does log the error for me (but that doesn't help). Attempting to eliminate `, error: {}()` from the function call returns a warning that the function now doesn't throw, which still doesn't help me.

The Objective C code that is generating the error is:

```
[persistentCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:EncryptedStoreType configuration:nil URL:databaseURL
        options:options error:error];

if (*error)
{
    NSLog(@"Unable to add persistent store.");
    NSLog(@"Error: %@\n%@\n%@", *error, [*error userInfo], [*error localizedDescription]);
}

return persistentCoordinator;
```

What is the correct syntax to capture the error in this case?

Comment: That's really weird — the `error` writeback parameter shouldn't be part of the imported function signature at all. Have you tried calling the function without passing `error: ...`?

Comment: The function is defined without the `error` bit in the header as well, so calling it that way doesn't throw at all.

Comment: That's probably the problem. Can you remove/hide that version from Swift?

Comment: I can do that, however, it still doesn't thrown even when generating the errors. But, I'm able to tell it's failing by checking the resulting object's properties, so I'll just do that instead.

Comment: How does this method behave in case of error? For Swift to properly understand its `throw`ing-ness, it has to set the out-param to a non-nil error *and also return nil* when an error is encountered.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't do that. I have the end of the function displayed at the end of my question.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps the appropriate thing to do is mark this functions return parameter as _Nonnull, which should prevent it from being imported as `throws`.